# Formatting of long numbers on Grafana

Tags: grafana

One of the columns has a number displayed as `1.0123121273324e+24` on Grafana dashboard - Table visualization. How do I make it display as is with no `e+24` and no decimal?
I tried override function and unit to none but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use the `string` unit to show the unformatted number. See [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/standard-options/#unit). However, it might be possible that the value already comes like this from Splunk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get numbers in this format *1.0034453732743108e+24* to be in this format *1,003,445,373,274,310,800,000,000* by changing the Unit type into "locale format" from the Visualization settings of a panel. That unit type can be found under the Misc unit types. Here's also a snapshot of my setting where I underlined the correct drop-down list with a red line.

[image: Grafana panel visualization settings]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the unit type to "locale format" also works when numbers are being trimmed by Grafana and the decimal point is removed - for example some values show as "100" and others show as "100.0" even when they're from the same dataset and in the database all values have the decimal points.